# Ideal Forms issue with showing form element when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, element, show-hide

I am using ideal forms and on step 4 there is radio button group that indicates the family status of the user and after that there is a div that named "wife" that keeps the spouse's data which is not displayed. What i want to achieve is when the radio button "married" is checked, the div "wife" to appear and when it is unchecked then to hide again. I have tried using js but still nothing!!! What am i doing wrong???

```js
$(function () {

  // If your using double quotes in your selector, the type/name designation needs to be surrounded by single
  // quotes. Opposite is true if you are using single quotes in your selector

  $("input[name='family']").change(function() {
    
    // Getting the radio value alows you to toggle #wife without having a 
    // seperate show-hide if statement for "single"
    
    var isChecked = $("input[name='family']:checked").val();

    if (isChecked == "married") {
      $('#wife').show();
    } else {
      $('#wife').hide();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="idealsteps-step">
    <div align="center">
        <label align="center">Στοιχεία Οικογενειακής Κατάστασης</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="main">Οικογενειακή Κατάσταση:</label>
        <p class="group">
            <label>
                <input name="family" type="radio" id="single" value="single">Άγαμος</label>
            <label>
                <input name="family" type="radio" id="married" value="married">Έγγαμος</label>
            <label>
                <input name="family" type="radio" id="divorced" value="divorced">Διαζευμγένος</label>
            <label>
                <input name="family" type="radio" id="symfono" value="symfono">Σύμφωνο Συμβίωσης</label>
            <label>
                <input name="family" type="radio" id="widower" value="widower">Χήρος</label>
        </p>
<span class="error"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="field" id="wife" name="spouse_data" style="display:none">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Στοιχεία Συζύγου</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="main">Ονοματεπώνυμο</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="main">Ημ/νία Γέννησης</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="spouse_fullname" type="text" data-idealforms-ajax="ajax.php">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="spouse_date_of_birth" type="text" placeholder="HH/MM/EEEE" class="datepicker">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="field buttons">
        <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Prev</button>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</section>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't enclosing the `$("input[type=radio]")` type designation in single quotes - eg `$("input[type='radio']")`. Since you have a name for your radio group, it might make more sense to bind to that directly..

**Example:**

```js
$(function() {

  // If your using double quotes in your selector, the type/name designation needs to be surrounded by single
  // quotes. Opposite is true if you are using single quotes in your selector

  $("input[name='family']").change(function() {
    
    // Getting the radio value alows you to toggle #wife without having a 
    // seperate show-hide if statement for "single"
    
    var isChecked = $("input[name='family']:checked").val();

    if (isChecked == "married") {
      $('#wife').show();
    } else {
      $('#wife').hide();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="idealsteps-step">
  <div align="center">
    <label align="center">Στοιχεία Οικογενειακής Κατάστασης</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="main">Οικογενειακή Κατάσταση:</label>
    <p class="group">
      <label>
        <input name="family" type="radio" id="single" value="single">Άγαμος</label>
      <label>
        <input name="family" type="radio" id="married" value="married">Έγγαμος</label>
      <label>
        <input name="family" type="radio" id="divorced" value="divorced">Διαζευμγένος</label>
      <label>
        <input name="family" type="radio" id="symfono" value="symfono">Σύμφωνο Συμβίωσης</label>
      <label>
        <input name="family" type="radio" id="widower" value="widower">Χήρος</label>
    </p>
    <span class="error"></span> 
  </div>
  <div class="field" id="wife" name="spouse_data" style="display:none">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Στοιχεία Συζύγου</strong>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="main">Ονοματεπώνυμο</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="main">Ημ/νία Γέννησης</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="spouse_fullname" type="text" data-idealforms-ajax="ajax.php">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="spouse_date_of_birth" type="text" placeholder="HH/MM/EEEE" class="datepicker">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="field buttons">
    <label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
    <button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Prev</button>
    <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</section>


<div class="field" id="wife" name="spouse_data" style="display:none">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Στοιχεία Συζύγου</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="main">Ονοματεπώνυμο</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="main">Ημ/νία Γέννησης</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="spouse_fullname" type="text" data-idealforms-ajax="ajax.php">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="spouse_date_of_birth" type="text" placeholder="HH/MM/EEEE" class="datepicker">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your prompt response. I ran your snippet and i really works!!! When i implement your code i still got nothing. I created a new html doc with nothing else but your code and still nothing. I am starting to lose it!!!!

Comment: I've changed my the code in my initial question according to your answer to show you that it doesn't work. Is there anything different in my snippet in comparison to your answer????

Comment: @ApostolisPanagos - you had a `<script>` tag in the javascript section of the snippet you posted that was causing it not to run. I edited your post and removed it - that's all I changed - and it appears to be working correctly.